# Insert data if not exist

Tags: php, insert

I have two tables `cw_users` and `ref_users`, both have a column named `id`.

I'm using ISAM so can't use a foreign key.
So now I wanted to insert `id` from `cw_users` into `ref_users` if it didn't exist.

This is what I did, but didn't help:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$ref_code=md5($id);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO ref_users (id) VALUES ('$id') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM cw_users where id='$id')");
```

Comment: `SELECT` what from `cw_users` in your `NOT EXISTS` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `INSERT IGNORE INTO`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ref_users (id)
VALUES ('$id')
```

It will insert if the value does not exist, and ignore the statement if it does.

Note that this will only work if `id` is the Primary Key

**EDIT:** It seems from your comments that you would be much better off using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Try this query

```
INSERT INTO ref_users(id, ref_code)
VALUES ('$id', '$ref_code')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
ref_code = '$ref_code'
```

Comment: This the whole code, which I'm using: `<?php
                            
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $ref_code=md5($id);
                            
  mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO ref_users (id) VALUES ('$id') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT your_id_field FROM cw_users where id='$id')");
                            
  echo $ref_code;
                            
  mysql_query("UPDATE ref_users SET ref_code='$ref_code' WHERE id='$id'");
                          
?>`

Comment: No, it doesn't show any error, the `$ref_code` gets inserted if the id exist

Comment: I answered your query, but you might want to tell your exact requirement in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
...WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

why not run normal insert, it will fail if row exists?

Comment: No, it worked, I added two queries, the one which inserts `id` fails if it already exist, while the other runs, though the answer given by @Ashwin Mukhija  was more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is

```
"INSERT INTO ref_users (id) VALUES ('$id') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM cw_users where id='$id')"
```

You **can't use were case in insert query** . you can use normal insert .